# Remove desktop shortcut Visual Studio Installer Projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, desktop, shortcut

I use Visual Studio Installer Projects with Visual Studio 2019 to build installers with a Desktop shortcut, but there is no way to remove that shortcut.

I have never seen an App capable of this, is there an option or did I do something wrong?
I just want users to be able to delete the shortcut.

[image: issue demonstration]

Comment: What do you mean with "Unable to delete shortcut?"

Comment: Maybe you are installing as administrator and trying to delete from another user?

Comment: @Emanuele I install it with the same user as the one that is trying to delete the shortcut. To delete it I can try either right click delete, drag to the trash, press Delete key, nothing works, I can only move it...

Comment: I added a Gif demonstrating the issue

Comment: Take a look at the following references: [Cannot delete shortcuts from desktop](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cannot-delete-shortcuts-from-desktop/7583c52e-6e7d-42c5-910f-23fbe99ebfcc) and [Can't delete a desktop shortcut](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cant-delete-a-desktop-shortcut/1e35da30-3543-4d4d-a465-fc78c06c2107)

Comment: @XingyuZhao I tried them all except Windows in Safe Mode, I cannot ask users to do that... didn't work :|

Comment: No one had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem and tried to comment here, but my post was deleted because it was deemed "not an answer". I'll try again...

The Desktop Shortcut created by the installer has the OWNER property set to SYSTEM, and if you change the owner to your username, then it can be deleted.

I reported the problem to Microsoft but they could not replicate the problem - see https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects&ssr=false#qna

I eventually gave up and used Inno Setup instead.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31861322)